Continuous selection from a upper hemicontinuity correspondence.
Given an upperhemicontinuous correspondence (see here for definition)$$F: A \rightrightarrows [0,1]$$ from a compact convex set $A \subset R^{d}$, is it possible to construct a continuous selection from it? A continuous selection here means a function $f: A \mapsto [0,1]$ such that $f(x) \in F(x), \forall x \in A$.

Please define (or give a reference) for "hemicontinuity" : it isn't a widespread term...

There is The Michael selection theorem but it may not be useful in your case since it concerns lower hemicontinuous correspondences

@EvangelopoulosFoivos Suppose, additionally, let us also assume lower hemicontinuity. Only restriction is that the sets $F(x)$ are not convex. Can we conclude something with this stronger hypothesis? The  Michael selection thm needs convexity assumption. Most such thms require convexity.

I am not sure what can be said without convexity
